# Haskell: Using the same operator on different types in a function

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple interpreter in Haskell. I have 3 possible variable types: `bool`, `int` and `string`. To avoid repetition in evaluating comparisons, I've written a function that takes 2 expressions and an operator:

```
data Value = IntVal Integer
           | StringVal String
           | BoolVal Bool
           | ...

evalComparison :: Ord a => Exp -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> Exp -> Result Value
evalComparison expr1 op expr2 = do
  val1 <- evalExp expr1
  val2 <- evalExp expr2
  return $ BoolVal $
    case (val1, val2) of
      (IntVal i1, IntVal i2)       -> op i1 i2 (*)
      (StringVal s1, StringVal s2) -> op s1 s2 (**)
      (BoolVal b1, BoolVal b2)     -> op b1 b2 (***)
      otherwise                    -> error "Expected values of the same type!"
```

It's intended usage is, for example:

```
evalExp :: Exp -> Result Value
...
evalExp (ELessThen e1 e2) = evalComparison e1 (<) e2
```

(And so on for other comparison operators).

The problem is - it doesn't work. GHC says it *couldn't match type Integer with [Char] in line* `(**)` and similarly *Integer with Bool in line*  `(***)`.

I think I know where the problem lies: once the `a` from the operator's type is determined as `Integer` in line `(*)`, it cannot be changed. So my question is twofold:

1. Why does this problem arise, provided that the result type (`Bool`) is always the same regardless of the operator's arguments' types?
2. What can be done to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature `a -> a -> Bool` says that there must exist some type `a` for which `op` has that type. But you want this to work for *more than one* type `a`. You can't do that in Haskell '98.

If you turn on rank-2 types (or rank-N types), then you can do

```
evalComparison :: Exp -> (forall a. a -> a -> Bool) -> Exp -> Result Value
```

This says that whatever you pass in as `op` has to work for *multiple* types `a`. In fact, it says that `op` has to work for *all possible types* `a`. But that's probably too much. What you want is probably closer to

evalComparison :: Exp -> (forall a. Ord a => a -> a -> Bool) -> Exp -> Result Value

This says that `op` has to work for every possible `a` that implements `Ord`.

Although frankly at that point, you might as well just call `compare` explicitly in your case-expression. Have `evalComparison` return an `Ordering`, and then apply a `Ordering -> Result Value` to that. `Ordering` is only one type, which should make things simpler.